# How to convert specified JSON format to a specific JSON format using JOLT transformation

Tags: json, jolt

I have below JSON data in one format (Source JSON) and trying to convert that JSON data to another JSON format (Target JSON) using [JOLT library](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception). I tried their demo site but keep getting parse error. I am not sure what am I missing. Can anyone please let me know what's the **Transformation JSON** I need to use to achieve the target JSON format? Thanks!

**Source JSON:**

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "identifier": "fa7242c8-6574-1c49-ju1f-5gad0659ecmt",
  "name": "App List",
  "structureType": "iteration",
  "hasChildren": true,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "identifier": "9990bffb-3edf-4d0b-8584-a542f792de91",
      "name": "AppNameOne",
      "structureType": "iteration",
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 783,
          "identifier": "03283159-9a79-4f21-8ead-55c071448d54",
          "name": "AppNameOne_03.14",
          "structureType": "iteration",
          "hasChildren": false,
          "attributes": {
            "startDate": "2018-12-01T00:00:00Z",
            "finishDate": "2019-02-08T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/AppNameOne/AppNameOne_03.14"
        },
        {
          "id": 1029,
          "identifier": "cc6b1e3b-a360-4a1e-afd2-629ca30e2cdf",
          "name": "AppNameOne_03.15",
          "structureType": "iteration",
          "hasChildren": false,
          "attributes": {
            "startDate": "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z",
            "finishDate": "2020-04-08T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/AppNameOne/AppNameOne_03.15"
        }
      ],
      "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/AppNameOne"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "identifier": "ddde31b8-33bd-4eb0-b531-b7958fc218d6",
      "name": "MyAppTwo",
      "structureType": "iteration",
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1485,
          "identifier": "5257534c-1949-4302-b1d1-ed1e36123645",
          "name": "MyAppTwo_03.53",
          "structureType": "iteration",
          "hasChildren": false,
          "attributes": {
            "startDate": "2023-04-01T00:00:00Z",
            "finishDate": "2023-08-01T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/MyAppTwo/MyAppTwo_03.53"
        },
        {
          "id": 1506,
          "identifier": "eac635b2-0221-471d-a3da-1d15d000186e",
          "name": "MyAppTwo_03.54",
          "structureType": "iteration",
          "hasChildren": false,
          "attributes": {
            "startDate": "2023-08-01T00:00:00Z",
            "finishDate": "2024-11-29T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/MyAppTwo/MyAppTwo_03.54"
        },
        {
          "id": 1511,
          "identifier": "b1e1a5cc-f6cd-490e-9419-c3cf5e241fa9",
          "name": "MyAppTwo_03.52HF",
          "structureType": "iteration",
          "hasChildren": false,
          "attributes": {
            "startDate": "2023-07-17T00:00:00Z",
            "finishDate": "2024-11-14T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/MyAppTwo/MyAppTwo_03.52HF"
        }
      ],
      "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/MyAppTwo"
    },
    {
      "id": 113,
      "identifier": "caf3744b-47b9-4da5-a6d5-8d85d9943e96",
      "name": "DBNameCon",
      "structureType": "iteration",
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 114,
          "identifier": "ea67184f-f01f-4240-a15f-e3be3d3a00b8",
          "name": "Sb15",
          "structureType": "iteration",
          "hasChildren": false,
          "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/DBNameCon/Sb15"
        },
        {
          "id": 115,
          "identifier": "730a3ea7-2b01-499f-9323-0f9c92058f6d",
          "name": "MS",
          "structureType": "iteration",
          "hasChildren": false,
          "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/DBNameCon/MS"
        }
      ],
      "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/DBNameCon"
    },
    {
      "id": 300,
      "identifier": "32a5316b-6b9c-4ce1-9aa1-cb647e90ad40",
      "name": "Iteration Name",
      "structureType": "iteration",
      "hasChildren": false,
      "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/Iteration%20Name"
    },
    {
      "id": 1448,
      "identifier": "a0b3871d-810a-4277-851e-52ed864b2915",
      "name": "_ParentApp",
      "structureType": "iteration",
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1449,
          "identifier": "3bc8f2fb-0261-49a0-99a7-5631607ab998",
          "name": "FeatureModule",
          "structureType": "iteration",
          "hasChildren": true,
          "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/_ParentApp/FeatureModule"
        }
      ],
      "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations/_ParentApp"
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations"
    }
  },
  "url": "http://tfs.orgname.org:8080/tfs/orgname/1s2ldda4-coda-4a0g-bg01-ueg59d97b086/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Iterations"
}
```

**Target JSON:**

```
{
   "options":[
      {
         "key":"AppNameOne_03.14",
         "value":"App List\AppNameOne\AppNameOne_03.14",
         "enabled":false
      },
      {
         "key":"AppNameOne_03.15",
         "value":"App List\AppNameOne\AppNameOne_03.15",
         "enabled":false
      },
      {
         "key":"MyAppTwo_03.53",
         "value":"App List\MyAppTwo\MyAppTwo_03.53",
         "enabled":false
      },
      {
         "key":"MyAppTwo_03.54",
         "value":"App List\MyAppTwo\MyAppTwo_03.54",
         "enabled":true
      },
      {
         "key":"MyAppTwo_03.52HF",
         "value":"App List\MyAppTwo\MyAppTwo_03.52HF",
         "enabled":true
      },
      {
         "key":"Sb15",
         "value":"App List\DBNameCon\Sb15",
         "enabled":true
      },
      {
         "key":"MS",
         "value":"App List\DBNameCon\MS",
         "enabled":true
      },
      {
         "key":"FeatureModule",
         "value":"App List\_ParentApp\FeatureModule",
         "enabled":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try to read your friendly manual and build the transformation spec?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need to loop within the inner `"children"` array. So, the following transformation might be used :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "children": {
        "*": {
          "children": {
            "*": {
              "name": ["&3_&1.key", "&3_&1.value"], copy the values of the "name" attribute twice
              "hasChildren": "&3_&1.enabled" // rename the attribute
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // nest whole JSON within the "options" array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "options[]"
    }
  }
]
```

where `"hasChildren"` presumed to be `"enabled"` as being the only attribute with boolean value

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: That is awesome. I had a small correction related to target json's **value**. Could you please help updating your answer? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Alvin , thanks. You could do with the characters other than backslash(I can edit the answer how to if you want), but I don't think we can handle it along with a backslash separator which is considered as special character and even not possible to escape I think(at least I don't know). Take care.